# "it's my stag do, so I won't"

Tags: conversation

Mr. A

Hi
I think I shall need more time to create the reports, so will not be sending you today.
I will get this finalised by discussing with Mr.Z although later.

Mr. B

OK, no problem. Please refer to Mr.Y or Z in my absence

Mr .A

ok thanks
Speak to you later. Have a nice holiday

Mr. B

it's my stag do, so I won't, but thank you anyway!

What is the meaning of what Mr. B said?

Comment: This needs a lot more context to know what's going on. Can you give the URL where you got this from or copy more of the dialog or explain more of the setting? Is there a party involved? Like before a wedding?

Comment: This is a question about *culture* and *social interaction*, not English language as such. The speaker is whimsically implying that he won't enjoy his forthcoming time off work for some reaon *specifically* connected to the fact that he's having a stag party. Perhaps he expects to be discomfited by teasing from co-celebrants. Perhaps he expects to get *very* drunk and spend a lot of time unpleasantly hung over. Perhaps he's having second thoughts about his upcoming marriage. How do we know?

Comment: Please see....I have updated the chat.

Comment: Which part is confusing you? If it's 'do' (which is usually a verb) you need to google "stag do" which will tell you what this is. If you don't understand why he won't enjoy himself, see @FumbleFingers comment.

Comment: Who is downvoting? There are a number of smart people who have left comments who didn't get the pun, so it's ***not*** obvious. And if you don't get the pun, the meaning is completely opaque.

Answer (score 2):

A **Stag Party** is a male only  party, especially a party (a '**do**') suffered by the groom shortly before his wedding day. It is often very undignified. [There may exceptionly be tame stag parties.](http://www.thestagcompany.com/)

Comment: Yeah, "my stag do" indicates this is a stag party in his honor (presumably in anticipation of his wedding), and, depending on the habits of his "friends", he may be subjected to some fairly onerous teasing and hazing.

Answer (score 1):

In all the comments, people seem to be saying that Mr. B is not going to enjoy himself. My interpretation is that he will definitely enjoy himself, just not in a "nice" manner. See [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nice).

> **nice**:
>   6 a :  socially acceptable :  well-bred ⟨from a nice family⟩,
>   6 b :  virtuous, respectable ⟨was taught that nice girls don't do that⟩.

It's a pun. It may only work in American English, since BrE dictionaries don't seem to contain this definition of *nice*.

If anybody needs more context, a stag party is an all-male party, often one given for a groom before his wedding and featuring entertainment which would not be considered "nice", according to the above definition.

Comment: I find your interpretation unlikely.  Perhaps if we knew that the speaker was fond of punning it would be somewhat likely, but that definition of "nice" is somewhat archaic to begin with.

Comment: I’m with @HotLicks here. Doesn’t seem likely that he’s talking about _nice_ at all to me—seems much more likely that he’s saying he’s out of the office for a day or two because of his stag do (a very exhausting and tiring thing), which is about as far from a holiday (a calming and relaxing thing) as you can get. He’s negating the _holiday_ bit, not the _nice_ bit.

Comment: So maybe it's an unsuccessful pun, or maybe Mr. B doesn't like stag parties. It's really impossible to tell without more context.

Comment: I don't know if I count as one of the [smart people who didn't get the pun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251832/its-my-stag-do-so-i-wont?noredirect=1#comment548994_251832). I wouldn't go so far as to say *nice = respectable* is archaic in BrE - but it's at least "dated", so such an oblique pun based on that sense seems unlikely, as @Hot Licks says. It would have worked for me if B had said *It's my stag do, so it'll probably be **nasty** rather than **nice***, but I'd still say it's a "micro-cultural" reference somewhat peculiar to A and B's normal "banter" interactions.